# Implementing a User Interface in the Style of Visual Studio 6 for a IDE

Tags: ide

Is there a Eclipse like [tool](http://www.eclipse.org/emf/) to build IDEs to build something similar to Visual Studio 98, something looking like [image: this]? 
I've seen a lot of IDE's similar to VS98. Are there standard controls for them?

I'm exploring this technology to allow the end user like a doctor to define state-based interactive dialogue based diagnosis systems for simple diseases. Example below: 
[image]

Comment: Can you clarify the question?  Why are you trying to build an IDE similar to Visual Studio 98, and what is it that you want it to do?

Comment: create state machines through IDE

Comment: do you want state machine as is diagrams? or as actual executable units? VS2008 + can do these.

Comment: State machine as a visual programming language for my IDE which I want to look similar to vs6

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but you could look at the [SharpDevelop open source IDE](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/) to get some ideas
[image]